# context mismatch error in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android application in which I am using table layout in the java file. I had given the reference of the xml file, but it is showing the context mismatch error. I am posting the code of the error line. Can any one help me on that topic?

```
TableRow rw1=new TableRow(R.id.tableRow3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring `TableRow` id by xml layout file then,It should be,

```
TableRow rw1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
```

Or if its just a java file's new view, Then it must be,

```
TableRow rw1=new TableRow(<yourActivity.this>);
```

Comment: it is showing a error in which it is asking for creating method findViewById to context.

Comment: Its your class extend activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
TableRow rw1=new TableRow(R.id.tableRow3);
```

The above constructor is not defined.. so use `TableRow rw1=new TableRow(yourActivity.this);`

if you want get the reference of alresdy existing view then use `findViewById(/*view id in xml*/)`

Comment: i am not getting this code TableRow rw1=new TableRow(yourActivity.this);